# Why doesn't SciLexer.dll load to my application in Windows 7?

Tags: vb.net, dll, editor, tabcontrol, scilexer.dll

I'm trying to create an HTML editor where you can edit, compile JavaScript, and preview your website. Compiling JavaScript (which work) and editing HTML are no longer a problem to me. The only problem I have is that after I build and debug my project in Visual Studio 2017, I moved to a Windows 7 machine to test it out. I was building the project in Windows 10. Later I found that when I compile my project in Windows 7, my main TabControl which was dock to "Fill", did not load a "Multiline TextBox" which I added earlier. I actually used a component called "FlatTabControl.dll" to make my TabControl look even better. I'd also added "SciLexer.dll" to the Debug folder. I obviously added my code to MainForm_Load as the following:

```
Dim [lib] As IntPtr = LoadLibrary("SciLexer.dll")

sci = CreateWindowEx(0, "Scintilla", "sciMain", WS_CHILD_VISIBLE_TABSTOP, 8, 83, Me.Width - 33, Me.Height - 145, Me.Handle, 0, New IntPtr(0), Nothing)
```

Later then, I tried replacing my TabControl with a default Windows TabControl. I copied the properties from the FlatTabControl component, but when I debugged it, it was docked "Fill" this replaced the whole screen with a white surface.

[ScreenShot Of The App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGlYj.png)

Here is a screenshot i provided from the application. The Tab that says "New File" is the FlatTabControl component and as you can see is not a default windows TabControl. Can anyone give me any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: I believe you could provide screenshots of what it should be and what it is now. Besides, personally I would suggest to try removing `FlatTabControl` first.

Comment: Instead of using the native library use [**ScintillaNET**](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET), which is a Scintilla wrapper for .NET applications (VB.NET, C#, etc.).

Comment: I've provided a screenshot like you ask, maybe it will get you to figure it out.